# How to set up a two-step workflow for email approvals

Tags: exm

When an email campaign gets created we want the content and the recipient list which has been added to the campaign to be reviewed by some other team member /user role.
So that the content is reviewed correctly and approved by the QA before it can be executed by the user.

So let say I am a User 1 with EXM Role and I create a campaign I should not be able to trigger the same without seeking approval from User 2 with EXM Advance Role. This is similar to content items with workflow.

Comment: Virtually everything in Sitecore is an item, and Workflows are applied to Item Templates.  Sounds like you should be able to single out the correct templates from your description above and assign some workflows to the `__StandardValues` of those.